# Prioritize Tasks in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, geolocation

I have a map application, and every time that the user moves the map I have to make a new request to the back-end to receive the points.

Right now I'm already optimizing a lot the process of getting the points. But I'd like to add prioritizing functionality to my Threads.

It's executing the Threads in serial (one before the other). But my optimizations work better when I already process a larger bound thread before.

Here is how I'm implementing my `AsyncTask` right now:

```
plotPinsThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, List<Loja>>() {

                final boolean oldMy = showMyStores;
                final boolean oldOthers = showOtherStores;

                @Override
                protected List<Loja> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        publishProgress(true);
                        Log.d(TAG, "=====> Inicio de requisição de pontos");
                        List<Loja> lojas = new ArrayList<>();

                        publishProgress(true);
                        if (showMyStores && !isCancelled()) {
                            publishProgress(true);
                            lojas.addAll(lojasDAO.getLojasList(cliente, currentBounds, LojaJsonDAO.DEALERSHIPS, this));
                        }

                        if (showOtherStores && !isCancelled()) {
                            publishProgress(true);
                            lojas.addAll(concorrentesDAO.getLojasList(others, currentBounds, LojaJsonDAO.COMPETITORS, this));
                        }

                        return lojas;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Erro de Json", e);
                    }

                    return new ArrayList<>();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... values) {
                    if (values[0]) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onCancelled() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Uma Thread foi cancelada: ");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<Loja> list) {
                    publishProgress(true);
                    boolean isLojasLoaded = lojasCarregadas.containsAll(list);

                    if (!isLojasLoaded && isEnoughZoom() && oldMy == showMyStores && oldOthers == showOtherStores && !isCancelled()) {
                        clearMarkers();
                        for (Loja loja : list) {
                            publishProgress(true);
                            if (loja.getPosition() != null) {
                                mMap.addMarker(getMarker(loja));
                            }
                        }
                        lojasCarregadas.addAll(list);
                        Log.d(TAG, "=====> Final de requisição de pontos");
                    } else {
                        String msg = (isLojasLoaded) ? "já carregados." : "invalidos";
                        Log.d(TAG, "=====> Final de requisição, dados " + msg);
                    }
                    publishProgress(false);


                }
            }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

I read something about executors and I had the insight of creating a executor that would implement a PriorityQueue where I would make the Threads with larger bounds execute before the smaller ones. (the param currentBounds)

I don't know how to do it, or if I should implement it with another thread approach.

PS: If I implements a Executor, is there some way to get the params of the AsyncTask on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom executor.  When you call execute(), it uses a default executor that runs all tasks serially.  If you call executeOnExecutor() you can specify an executor.  The default one is serial, there's also THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR which will run tasks in parallel.  If you want a priority queue, you'll need to write your own that keeps a priority queue of tasks and executes them serially based on priority.

Comment: Would I have to implements it from Executor class? How would I get the currentBounds var to make my compression of what thread should have bigger priority?